# Update a row in react table without re-render the table

Tags: reactjs, updates, tabular

I have a big data collection and I load it into  a [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table). Data in cells will be changed in server and will be pushed (web socket) from server. Instead of re-render the entire large table, I am looking for a way to update individual cell.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `react-table` should do it manually for you

Comment: Did we find a way to update individual cell ?